# How to compute $\int_0^2(1+4t^2+9t^4)^{1/2}\text{d}t$?

Tags: integration, parametric

The original question was:

find the length $\ell$ of the curve $\gamma$ given the parametric equations:

$$x=t~~~~~ y=t^2~~~~~ z=t^3 $$

from $t=0$ to $t=2$

Comment: I can say by a simple look that this integral cannot be solved with elementary function. Indeed I bet that there will be some Elliptic Integral hidden inside the result.

Comment: yeah the wolfram solution involved nonelementary integrals. is there an easier way?

Comment: If this is your integral, then there are no easier ways. Unless you want a REALLY approximate solution, which would be really bad in the neighborhood of $2$. Are you sure about this? Seems a really strange exercise. Did you take it from a book?

Comment: It was a midterm question

Comment: It's also impossible to solve in easier ways. So I think of a book misprint, as you can see by the total result below.

Answer (score 1):

I bet there must be some error in this question because the indefinite integral looks monstrous, as Kim Peek already forsaw. It must be kind of Elliptic one. (I calculated the integral with wolfram)

[image]

How ever numerically the value between $0$ and $2$ is $9.57057$ [See here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28sqrt%281%2B4*t%5E2%2B9*t%5E4%29,0,2%29)

Comment: Gosh, that was ways ways ways worse than what I thought! Surely it cannot be calculated by hands that easily (mostly in some basic calculus course). Thank you for the explicit result!

Answer (score 1):

For sure, this is a monster and numerical integration would be required.

However, I was able to get "reasonable" results expanding the integrand as a Taylor series around $t=1$ and integrating between the given bounds. Since the integrand is now $$\sqrt{9 t^4+4 t^2+1}=\sum_{i=0}^n \alpha_i(t-1)^i+O\left((t-1)^{n+1}\right)$$ $$\int_0^2\sqrt{9 t^4+4 t^2+1}\,dt=\sum_{i=0}^n \alpha_i\int_0^2(t-1)^i\,dt=\sum_{i=0}^n \alpha_i \frac{1+(-1)^i}{1+i}=2\sum_{i=0}^n  \frac{\alpha_{2i}}{2i+1}$$ 
I give below a table for a few results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & integral \\
 0 & 7.48331 \\
 2 & 9.57050 \\
 4 & 9.59621 \\
 6 & 9.58476 \\
 8 & 9.56654 \\
 10 & 9.56044 
\end{array}
\right)$$

which are very quickly "close" to the numerical value already reported in
loved.by.Jesus's answer.